# Hive SQL: how to insert only newer records into a table?

Tags: sql, hive

I have 3 tables. I'm inserting data from t1 into t2 and t3. I would like to only insert the data from t1 that is newer than the newest data already in t2.

This is my current select statement:

```
from (select *, concat(column1, '|', column2) as id from t1 
  where column1 = "value1") t
insert into table t2
  select 
  column3,
  id
insert into t3
  select 
  column4
  id
```

t1, t2 and t3 also contain a column "ttime", of type timestamp. I would like to modify my insert statement above to only insert data

```
where t1.ttime > max(t2.ttime)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
with subreq as (select max(time) from t2)
insert into t2 select * from t1 where t1.time>subreq.time
```

Just make a query `with` and then you can reference any column inside it for your further operations

Comment: What is the correct syntax? I tried:

with subreq as (select max(ttime) from t2)
from 
  (select *, concat(column1, '|', column2) as id t1
  where column1 = "value1" 
  and ttime>subreq.ttime
) t
insert into table t2 ....

and I get an error:

 Invalid table alias or column reference 'subreq'

Comment: I don't see that hive supports WITH in multi table insert statements: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Comment: oh... indeed :/